# Python discord.py bot not pushing embedded message with send message button

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, discord-buttons

So I've coded a discord.py bot that sends embedded messages to channel via the bot DM to keep things neat and orderly.  However, I added a send message button to my code to ask me whether I want to send this message or not before it actually pushes to the channels the bot is in as a protection layer incase I have edits to message (spelling, grammar, content, etc.).

The code I add brings up the send message button, but it still pushes to the channel first from the initial message, then it brings up the message button, and when I click on the message button it says invalid.

The console traceback states:  'button' object has no attribute 'response'

I've been flipping the code, editing here, and adding there, reading what others have tried in chat threads and I'm at a loss.

Hoping some one can assist me with this code to fix the missing link as I'm sure it's something small I'm missing.

MY CODE

```
import os
import os
import discord
import datetime
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord import Embed
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Intents
from typing import Optional
from keep_alive import keep_alive
import os

intents = discord.Intents.all()

bot = Bot(command_prefix= "!", intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Ready For War")
  print("---------")

###OPEN ANNOUNCEMENT####

@bot.command(name='oa')
async def oa(ctx, *, text):
  message = ctx.message
  view = Menu()
  await ctx.reply(view=view)

  embed = discord.Embed(title = "TWR Open Announcement", description = f"{text}", color = discord.Color.dark_blue())
  embed.set_footer(text="TWR LLC ~ Not Financial Advice - Education Only ~ TWR Social Medias @traderswarroom ~ Let's Go To War!!")

#test server 
  channel = bot.get_channel(1116126561582731397)
  await channel.send('@everyone', embed=embed)

##BUTTONS TO CODE##

class Menu(discord.ui.View):
    def init(self):
        super().init()
        self.value = None

    @discord.ui.button(label="Send Message", style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey)
async def menu1(self, button : discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message()

keep_alive()

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your arguments for your button are mixed up, it should be this way around, with the interaction *before* the button:

```py
@discord.ui.button(label="Send Message", style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey)
async def menu1(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
    await interaction.response.send_message("test")
```

Docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=button#discord.ui.button

The order was changed during the discord.py 2.0 beta. Maybe the resources you were looking at were a bit outdated.

Comment: Ok, finally the message button worked without an on screen error (great), but new message came that stated:

Cannot send an empty message

Comment: Here is the traceback; 

  File "main.py", line 45, in menu1
    await interaction.response.send_message()

discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message

Comment: @TradersWarRoom Sorry I was assuming you were just leaving out the message for the example, but yes you do have to send some content in your message. `await interaction.response.send_message("test")`